# Conditional won't trigger when given a 75: android

Tags: java, android, collision-detection, collision, android-drawable

Ok, so this is probably a silly question from an amateur programmer trying to experiment his way into basic use of Android graphics, but here it is.

In order to familiarize myself with 2D Android graphics to help out a friend of mine who wants me to use his idea for his game, I decided to try and make a simple version of pong. (simple meaning I haven't even made both paddles move yet)

Going off of the [Android API guides](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html), I built the experimental application around a custom View object (`PongView`) that has 3 `ShapeDrawable` objects (`rectangles`). The two paddles (I called them sticks) and the ball. I implemented a `MotionEventListener` into the View and made the left stick move with it (yay I figured something out :).

After that, I made the ball move by using a delayed `Runnable` created in the main activity that calls an update method inside the custom View. In the update method, I made a collision handler that reverses the ball's vector (on a specific axis) when it hits the sides of the screen or any sides of the paddles.

But after playing around with it, I saw that one of my collision conditions were not firing. The ball would pass through the bottom and the right side of the stick, bouncing when it hits the left side or the top.

Here are the collision conditions:

```java
//collisions
if ((bx + bside == getMeasuredWidth() || bx == 0) || //hit right or left of screen
        ((bx + bside == lx || bx == lx + width) && (by < ly + height && by > ly)) || //hit left stick
        ((bx + bside == rx || rx + width == bx) && (by < ry + height && by > ry))) { //hit right stick
    bVectorX = -bVectorX;
    System.out.println("bounce x");
}
if ((by + bside == getMeasuredHeight() || by == 0) ||
        ((by + bside == ly || by == ly + height) && (bx < lx + width && bx > lx)) ||
        ((by + bside == ry || by == ry + height) && (bx < rx + width && bx > rx))) {
    bVectorY = -bVectorY;
    System.out.println("bounce y");
}
```

- bside: side length (pixels) of the ball square
- width: width of paddles
- height: height of paddles
- bVectorX: change in coordinate (pixels) per update on the x-axis
- bx: x-coordinate of the ball
- by: y-coordinate of the ball
- lx: x-coordinate of the left-paddle

Trying to narrow down the problem area, I commented out all except this statement as this statement was giving me the trouble (at least on the x-axis):

```
bx == lx + width
```

I realized that since `lx` never changed during runtime, I could plug in the raw value (75) for testing and see if that caused the condition to trigger. It didn't. So I decided to try 76 instead, and guess what, it worked! I have no idea why, but it worked. the ball bounced at that line of pixels. So I tried putting the variables back in, trying:

```
bx == lx + width + 1
bx == lx + width - 1
```

and they both worked! When I took away the one +/- 1 however, it would go right through the paddle and bounce out from hitting the other side. (since all I do is reverse the vector). What I want it to do is hit the right side of the paddle and reverse the vector.

I have no idea why this is happening, thanks in advance for your help :)

EDIT: So I tested the conditional and found that these two pieces of code return true.

```
if (75 == 75) {

    int i = 75;
    if (i == 75) {
```

But this still never returns true.

```
if (bx == 75) {
```

Thanks again for the support. :)

Comment: +1 for the detailed post. I've tried coding collisions before, but that's too looooong ago. Gonna go ahead and support this post by upvoting it instead. Cheers!

Comment: @int j Thanks so much for the upvote and edit, I hope this can be solved. I may add in an edit with my latest conditional tests.

Comment: Go on right ahead. The more relevant details you can provide, the better.

Comment: could it be that bx is not 75.. so therefore its not true? You need to add logs to see what the values are at runtime and also you need to see if width is actually changing as well. Also standards wise 'bx == lx + width' looks like a typo, it should probably be 'bx = lx + width' but without the actual requirement or expected behavior we can only speculate.

Comment: @JoxTraex I think 'bx == lx + width' is a conditional, a regular = is for setting variables. And I think I know why the problem is occurring after I added the logs like you said, will post answer when I have working code.

Comment: Is bVectorX ever greater than 1 or less than -1? If so, it could just be jumping over the boundary. You could switch to using less than/greater than operators to avoid that. i.e. bx <= lx + width

Comment: Maybe it's naive question, but what's the bx type? Is in int or float?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be checking for exact equality i.e. `if (bx == 75) {}` as this condition to detect a collision would be met **only** if your `bVectorX` had very limited set of values (i.e. only integers that added or subtracted to/from `bx` would always make it to value `75`).

Just use `<=` and `>=` and you should be fine.

The same holds for detecting collisions with the screen edges.